# Proof dy/dx dx/dy = I

Tags: machine-learning, probability, linear-algebra

Denote $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^d $, $f(\mathbf{x}) = (f_1(\mathbf{x}), f_2(\mathbf{x}), \cdots, f_d(\mathbf{x}))$, $f_i: \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $i = 1, 2, \cdots, d$. I want to proof the fact that $\frac{\partial f(\mathbf{x})}{\partial \mathbf{x}} \frac{\partial \mathbf{x}}{\partial f(\mathbf{x})} = I$, where $I$ is the identity matrix.

Here is what I have done:

\begin{align*}
    \left[\frac{\partial \mathbf{x}}{\partial f(\mathbf{x})} \frac{\partial f(\mathbf{x})}{\partial \mathbf{x}}  \right]_{ij}
    &= \sum_{k=1}^d \left[\frac{\partial \mathbf{x}}{\partial f(\mathbf{x})}\right]_{ik} \left[\frac{\partial f(\mathbf{x})}{\partial \mathbf{x}} \right]_{kj}  \\
    &=  \sum_{k=1}^d \frac{\partial x_i}{\partial f_k(\mathbf{x})} \frac{\partial f_k(\mathbf{x})}{\partial x_j} \\
    &= \sum_{k=1}^d \frac{\partial x_i}{\partial x_j} \\
    &= \left\{
        \begin{aligned}
            0 & , & \text{if $i \neq j$} \\
            d & , & \text{if $i = j$}
        \end{aligned}
        \right.
\end{align*}
which is not equal to $I$.

Where is the problem?

Comment: You did not apply the chain rule correctly in the third line.

Comment: could you explain it in more detail?

Answer (score 0):

If $x_i = x_i(f_1(\mathbf{x}), f_2(\mathbf{x}),\ldots, f_d(\mathbf{x}))$, then
$$\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial x_j} = \sum_{k=1}^d \frac{\partial x_i}{\partial f_k} \cdot \frac{\partial f_k}{\partial x_j}$$
Note that the sum isn't on the left-hand side.

Comment: ahh, I see. I didn't apply the chain rule correctly. But now how to prove dy/dx dx/dy = I?